# How to open downloaded Kindle files in Android?

Tags: kindle-for-android

I have downloaded the [Kindle app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.kindle) from Google Play Store and installed it.

I have some Kindle files downloaded from the internet. How can I open them using my Kindle app?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have the [Kindle app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.kindle) installed, just open it and it should show a selection of the books you've purchased from the Kindle store.

Books that haven't been downloaded to your device yet are available via the "Archived Items" menu option that pops up when you press your device's <kbd>Menu</kbd>, you should be able to select and download any books there.

If you've downloaded Kindle compatible books from elsewhere on the internet, then if you move them into the "Kindle" folder on your SD card, they should appear in the listing of books when you open the Kindle app.

You have two options to do this:

- Plugging your phone into a PC and mounting the SD card as an external drive,
- Using one of the many [Android file manager](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=file%20manager&c=apps) apps that are available from Google Play Store.

Comment: **NOTE:** To find the `Kindle` folder, you first need to go into Kindle Settings and enable Data Storage Access for personal documents. Until you do, you won't have a `Kindle` folder on your device.

Comment: What if I've DL'd the book directly to my phone? I don't have an SD card directory that I can find.

Comment: I created a `books` folder at the top level of my `Internal Storage`, and then enabled Data Storage Access (thanks @NightOwl888!), and then my .mobi file appeared in the library. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to email the file to your Kindle email address.

When you setup your Kindle, Amazon assigns your Kindle account an email, [something]@free.kindle.com. Attach it to an email and send it there. Done.

Comment: You know, in a typical monopolistic move, Amazon is constantly deprecating it's own formats and products, and they announced very soon that they're not going to accept anymore their own mobi and azw formats.